# How to make a column invisible in an ssrs matrix

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have an ssrs matrix , the design of which looks like this :

[image]

The sql query used in the above dataset looks like this :

```
select [YEAR], [MONTH] as MONT , ProductName, NumberofSales from XYZ ;
```

When the report is run , My output looks like this :

[image]

Here , the Column Names 9 , 10 correspond to the months 9 - September and 10 - October.

Change shows the difference in numbers between the month and the previous month . example :
number of sales in october - number of sales in september.

I would like to remove the column that I have circled in the above picture . Could you please let me know how I can do this . ??

I already tried right clicking the **Change** column and changing the visibility property, by adding an expression to look soomething like this  :

```
=(Parameters!UserSelectedDate.Value=Fields!MONT.Value)
```

But that gives me an entire blank space for the Change column like this :

[image]

But I do, not want to see the blank space. I would like to remove the column completely. 
Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Try setting the visibility on the group rather than the column.

Comment: Also, check that ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace = true in the report properties http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11153/consumecontainerwhitespace-property-to-remove-blank-space-in-ssrs-2008-report.aspx

Comment: changing the visibitlity on the group is hiding both the columns in the group .. in my case it hides both the change column that I want to hide and the column 9. But I would like to see the column 9

Comment: Oh.  I see what you are getting at.  Did you try the consumecontainerwhitespace property?

Comment: Yes I tried that too just now . It doesnt help in my case, I think it only helps if you have extra blank pages. Thanks for trying to help.  :-)Let me know if anything else strikes.

Comment: I've tried a few times and I can't replicate your problem.. Every time I hide the right column in the group, it hides and leaves no gap...

Comment: Check your Error List when you preview it. The formula refers to "Month" and your dataset has it called "Mont".

Comment: Hey Thank you ! I have it as MONT since I was trying to bypass some other error on my report. On my report the formula is also listed as Mont. I made the correction in the report.

Comment: Set the "allow shrink" to true for the column to get rid of the white space.

Comment: Hey ShellNinja ! You mean the "CanShrink" property right ? I just tried that too.. Doesnt work in my case.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, why it shows blank space, but here is how I handled this problem:

1. Choose "column visibility" property of column "Change"
   [image]
2. Then I added expression for hiding column: `=IIF(Month(Fields!Date.Value)=Parameters!UserSelectedDate.Value,True,False)`

And when I select report parameter to 1 and preview the report, it hides Change column for month 1:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer works only for matrixed (varied count) columns.
But in all reports client want to group report data dynamicly and select column that one want to see.
So if I have matrix for example with columns -

[Store] [Good] [Amount Jan] [Amount Feb]....      [Amount Dec]

I can hide any column with Amount but If I right click on column Store - No option in menu- Column properties and option Column Visibility - Disabled. If apply visibility to cells - you'll see a blank space.

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for an answer for this issue and was frustrated that I could not find any. Then I found a workaround for this issue, I decided to share this.

You have to create column groups for all columns, which you would like to Show/Hide. For this matter you have to take or create one or more attributes in you ResultSet, which contain a constant value, so that the columns will not be later propagated.

[image]

After you created a new Column Group (as Adjacent Before/After)

[image]

you can put there the columns, which you like to Hide/Show.

[image]

After that you can use the property "Column visibility". It works just fine for me.

[image]