# Conditional Column Visability in SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have written a stored procedure which bring back a data set as below:

```
Sales Office | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr --- Continuing to EOYear and then a total

Office 1      Sales Amount in each Month.
Office 2
```

I then have this in SSRS.

I wish to show only the months which are required in the data set (chosen via parameter)

eg. April to June will show

```
Sales Office | Apr | May | June

Office 1    The figures for these months
Office 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a column invisible in an ssrs matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413710/how-to-make-a-column-invisible-in-an-ssrs-matrix)

Comment: Have you tried writing an expression for the column or column group visibility property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not saying I had used a date range with variables in my SPROC.

In the end I amended the stored procedure using a pivot and case statement combo which left me with the ability to have a 0 value inside the date range (between the variables) and everything outside the date range as NULL.

I then hid the NULL valued columns in SSRS and added a Total as a final column to keep everyone anywhere in the world happy forever.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to include the parameter in your stored procedure so that it only returns the data that you actually want to display:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyReport(@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE)
AS
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(TheDateTime AS DATE) >= @StartDate
AND CAST(TheDateTime AS DATE) <= @EndDate
```

And then your query in SSRS will need to have those parameters - once you add the "@" symbol in your query, SSRS will automatically create the parameters for you, though you'll need to double-click them and change them to dates.

IMHO it's easier to use a table-valued-function instead of a stored procedure: procs should only be used if something needs to be done, while a TVF should be used when you're just pulling data.